# Tomcat+Wicket sporadic NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, tomcat, wicket, classloader

I sporadically encounter the following exception when loading a specific page:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.app.item.search.SearchResultPanel
        at com.app.item.search.SearchResultPage.initialize(SearchResultPage.java:86)
        at com.app.core.layout.BasePage.onInitialize(BasePage.java:147)
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.fireInitialize(Component.java:864)
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.internalInitialize(MarkupContainer.java:955)
        at org.apache.wicket.Page.isPageStateless(Page.java:464)
        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.mapper.AbstractBookmarkableMapper.getPageInfo(AbstractBookmarkableMapper.java:447                                                                                                                  )
        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.mapper.AbstractBookmarkableMapper.mapHandler(AbstractBookmarkableMapper.java:391)
        at org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.mount.UnmountedMapperAdapter.mapHandler(UnmountedMapperAdapter.java:61)
        at org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.mount.MountMapper.mapHandler(MountMapper.java:145)
        at org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.CompoundRequestMapper.mapHandler(CompoundRequestMapper.java:215)
        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.mapUrlFor(RequestCycle.java:429)
        at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:271)
        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:862)
        at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:261)
        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:218)
        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:289)
        --- CUT ---
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

The problem solves itself by restarting tomcat (maybe 2, 3,4 or 5 times) and it only happens when I deploy to the development/integration environment. On my development VM it never happened. And it affects only a couple of pages/panel (always them).

The SearchResultPanel is a simple class which extends the wicket Panel class.

On the catalina.out I see that the search results are loaded from Lucene but when it came to display the page I receive the above exception and a 404 page from wicket/tomcat.

The constructor of SearchResultPanel:

```
public SearchResultPanel(String id, final SearchResult resultList)
```

The line generating the exception (SearchResultPage:86):

```
SearchResultPanel resultPanel = new SearchResultPanel("searchResults",
                results);
```

The SearchResultPanel is found in the WEB-INF folder of the app:

```
# locate SearchResultPanel
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/item/search/SearchResultPanel$1.class
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/item/search/SearchResultPanel$2.class
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/item/search/SearchResultPanel$3.class
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/item/search/SearchResultPanel$4.class
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/item/search/SearchResultPanel$5.class
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/item/search/SearchResultPanel$6.class
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/item/search/SearchResultPanel$7.class
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/item/search/SearchResultPanel$8.class
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/item/search/SearchResultPanel$ItemFragment$1.class
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/item/search/SearchResultPanel$ItemFragment$2.class
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/item/search/SearchResultPanel$ItemFragment$3.class
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/item/search/SearchResultPanel$ItemFragment.class
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/item/search/SearchResultPanel$SortImageModel.class
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/item/search/SearchResultPanel.class
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/item/search/SearchResultPanel.html
```

Using:

- Wicket: 6.14.0
- Apache Tomcat/7.0.26

Can you please advise me further how to debug this class-loading problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: check client and server side java version,if you use lower version of java in server side it may happen

Comment: Such exception typically means that there was Exception thrown in `static` block of class. Please check that.

Comment: I had the same problem. I restart and it's fine but it is enoying.